# right rotates the given array of characters n position to right

Tags: java

A) Develop body of the methods

void rightRotate (char [] arr, int n)

The method right rotates the given array of characters n position to right.

For example if  arr = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' }, and n=2, then the result should be arr={'d', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c'}

B) Develop body of the methods

void leftRotate (char [] arr, int n)

The method left rotates the given array of characters n position to left..

For example if  arr = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'} then the result should be arr={'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b'}

---

I only learned java for one month, and this is a quiz this week.

the teacher ask us only use a temp and basic for loop to solve it.

and we cant use a new array.

---

```
public static void rightRotate(char arr[], int n)
{
    // Your code goes here
  int i;
   if(arr.length>1)
  {
  char p=arr[arr.length-n-1];
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
        char m= arr[arr.length-n+i];
        arr[arr.length-n-1+i]=arr[i];
        arr[i]=m;
     }
  arr[arr.length-1]=p;
}
}
```

this is what i wrote for the right rotate. but i cant figure out the left rotate one.

---

and my code has a bug in the test case 4.

Test Case 1:
array:  a  b  c  d  e
right rotated : d  e  a  b  c

Test Case 2:
array: a  b  c  d  e  f  g
right rotated : d  e  f  g  a  b  c

Test Case 3:
array: a  b
right rotated : b  a

Test Case 4:
array: a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n
right rotated : h  i  j  k  l  m  n  b  c  d  e  f  a  g

---

how can i improve the right rotate one? and what should i do for the left rotate one?

Thanks

Comment: Please show what you have attempted, and explain the specific problem (if any) that you are experiencing. Once you do that, a bunch of very smart people here will be happy to help solve that problem. Stack Overflow is here to help you solve specific problems, not do your homework for you.

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: what is debugging? we haven't learnt debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You would actually need two `for` loops to perform the rotation, one to maintain the number of rotations and one to shift the elements. Below should work:

```
public static void rightRotate(char arr[], int n) {
    int i;
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            char p = arr[arr.length - 1];
            //Shift the elements to the right
            for(int j = arr.length-2; j >= 0 ; j--){
                arr[j+1] = arr[j];
            }
            arr[0] = p;
        }
    }
}
```